# Regex not working correctly in JavaScript sorting function

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a problem with a sorting JS plugin for my tables. It's named "Sortable". When you checkout the documentation of this plugin you can find out that you can define your custom sorting types:

https://github.hubspot.com/sortable/api/options/

So I've defined my custom filter and named it `price`:

```
sortable.setupTypes([{
    name: "numeric", defaultSortDirection: "descending", match: function (a) {
        return a.match(d)
    }, comparator: function (a) {
        return parseFloat(a.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ""), 10) || 0
    }
}]);
```

It works particular great but when I add a refund price it works not correctly:

My normal price: `2.372,11 €`
My refund price: <del>`765,38 €`</del>`0,00 €`

When the function extracts the refund price, the outcome looks like this: `765,38 € 0,00 €` but I must look like this `000`.

So I've setup my regex this way `/[^0-9-]/g` but it's not filtering the `del` price. Logically the regex needs to get modified the way that it starts after the first `€_` or something like this.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something like this

```
a.replace(/^.*?([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\s*€\s*$/, "$1$2")
```

https://regex101.com/r/FHOYja/1

Comment: Looks good but enter this here like a value: 2.076,14 € seems to be an issue.

Comment: @Mr.Jo replace `([0-9]+),([0-9]+)`with `([0-9]*).?([0-9]+),([0-9]+)` and your replace with `$1$2$3`. This includes a optional sumber block with a following dot at the start of the price => `^.*?([0-9]*).?([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\s*€\s*$`

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! Works great :o

Answer (score 0):

A regex to grab everything after the first "€ " would be `(?<=€ ).*$` example on regex101:https://regex101.com/r/pULCel/1

Comment: Regex101 reports a pattern error. That's because lookbehinds are not *officially* supported - AFAIK, Chrome has them but not all browsers.